# Division by multiple subtraction in Assembly code (NASM)

Tags: assembly, nasm, division

I am trying to perform a division by multiple subtraction in assembly code and am getting the following errors:

```
subtract.nasm:19: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
subtract.nasm:20: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
subtract.nasm:24: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
subtract.nasm:25: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

I cannot figure this out, any ideas on what it could be?

```
section .data

        VAL1: db 10
        VAL2: db 2

section.text

        global _start
_start:

        mov eax, VAL1
        mov ecx, VAL2
        mov ebx, 0

sub_loop:

        sub eax,eax,ebx
        add ebx,ebx,1

        test eax,eax
        jnz sub_loop
        add edx,eax,ecx
        sub ebx,ebx,1

        mov eax,1
        mov ebx,0
        int 80h
```

Comment: `add ebx,ebx,1` There's no such form of `add`. Same goes for `sub`. Perhaps you meant to use `add ebx,1` (or `inc ebx`).

Comment: x86 is a CISC machine where typical instructions have only 2 operands, not 3.  Look at basically any x86 example or compiler output or manual.  IDK if you were trying to port ARM or MIPS code or something?

Comment: i am trying to do the equivalent of += 1 for the ebx,ebx, 1. I was looking at a similar example written in ARM, that is likely why you say that.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter and Michael!